# The Foundry Nuke NDK: 3d to 2d camera projection

Tags: c++, nuke

I am struggling a bit to calculate an accurate projected point from 3d to the 2d render camera using the Nuke NDK. I have a dynamic amount of data (for the test below I'm simply using a constant 8 points) that I'm looking to calculate so it seems impractical to package up reconcile nodes in a gizmo for this purpose.

I've been trying to follow the `nukescripts.snap3d.projectpoint` example, but so far I am quite significantly off.

An example of the data I'm getting:

```
PointA: 
(3D) { -127.91322327, 56.28646469, 336.15023804 } 
(2D) { 901.65655518, 65.55204773 }

PointF: 
(3D) { -127.91322327, 90.09331512, 372.51187134 }
(2D) { 522.12438965, 22.69236374 }
```

The data via a `Reconcile3d` node:

```
PointA: { 469.26919556, -1.9122355 }
PointF: { 522.12438965, 188.99978638 }
```

Can anyone see where I am mathematically failing. I wasn't expecting to run into these issues, but have been stuck for nearly 2 days just on these projections. Thanks.

```
//has camera && point data

if (input1() && input0()) {
    const Format *format = input0()->deepInfo().format();
    Matrix4 xform = input1()->imatrix(); // also tried the non-inverse matrix
    Matrix4 projection = input1()->projection() * xform;

    float imageAspect = float(format->h()) / float(format->w());
    float pixelAspect = format->pixel_aspect();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int s = i * 3;
        Vector4 v = projection * Vector4(
            XYZ_values[s], XYZ_values[s + 1], XYZ_values[s + 2], 1.0f
        );

        float x = ((v.x / v.w) + 1) * 0.5;
        float y = ((v.y / v.w) + (1- (1- imageAspect/pixelAspect))) * 0.5;                         
         x *= float(format->w());
         y *= float(format->w()) * pixelAspect;

         XY_values.push_back(x);
         XY_values.push_back(y);
     }
}
```